# Error using vector as container adaptor for stack

Tags: c++, stl, stack, containers

I can't make things work out with container adaptors of the class stack on STL.
Here's the code:

```
typedef stack <int, vector<int> > vector_stack;

...

int main()
{
    vector_stack vec;

    vec.push(10);
    vec.push_back(20);
    vec.push_back(30);
    vec.pop();
    cout << vec[0] << vec[1];

    ...

}
```

It passes through .push(10) as expected because it's a stack member function,
but .push_back as a vector member function it doesn't accept. The error is:

```
'class std::stack<int, std::vector<int> >' has no member named 'push_back'
```

Answer (score 2):

`push_back` is not a member of `std::stack`, even though it's a member of the underlying container type. That's just the way it's defined. You must use `push`.

If you want a "vector stack" personally I would use `std::vector` directly, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Hmm... I thought I could do that after seeing somewhere that declaring vector as the underlying container you could use `operator[]` to access the elements of the `stack`. At least `vector` has the same `pop` aka `pop_back` and `push` aka `push_back` functions of a stack. thanks anyway.

Comment: @alfablac: No. The underlying container is just that: an underlying place to put the data. It doesn't alter the semantics or interface of stacks. That would be entirely pointless!

Answer (score 0):

Stack is container adapter i.e simply an interface to a container of the type passes to it as a template argument. All stack does is to eliminate the non-stack operations on its container from the interface and give back(), push_back() and pop_back() their conventional names top(), push() and pop()

Also, by default stack makes a deque to hold its elements but any sequence that provides back(), push_back() and pop_back() can be used.